# How to define and load your own shell function in zsh

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I am having a hard time defining and running my own shell functions in zsh. I followed [the instructions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html) on the official documentation and tried with easy example first, but I failed to get it work.

I have a folder:

```
~/.my_zsh_functions
```

In this folder I have a file called `functions_1` with `rwx` user permissions. In this file I have the following shell function defined:

```
my_function () {
echo "Hello world";
}
```

I defined `FPATH` to include the path to the folder `~/.my_zsh_functions`:

```
export FPATH=~/.my_zsh_functions:$FPATH
```

I can confirm that the folder `.my_zsh_functions` is in the functions path with `echo $FPATH` or `echo $fpath`

However, if I then try the following from the shell:

```
> autoload my_function
> my_function
```

I get:

> zsh: my_test_function: function definition file not found

Is there anything else I need to do to be able to call `my_function` ?

### Update:

The answers so far suggest sourcing the file with the zsh functions. This makes sense, but I am bit confused. Shouldn't zsh know where those files are with `FPATH`? What is the purpose of `autoload` then?

Comment: Make sure you have the $ZDOTDIR properly defined. http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html

Comment: The value of $ZDOTDIR is not related to this problem. The variable defines where zsh is looking for a user's configuration files. If it is unset $HOME is used instead, which is the right value for almost everybody.

Comment: I agree that sourcing isn't the `zsh` way, but if you intend to use your dotfiles (or parts of them) across your zsh and bash configs, then using `source` is the only option that you have.

Comment: On bash compatibility: This question is concerned with zsh's loadable function system. It has nothing to do with bash (and to my knowledge has not equivalent in bash). Sourcing files from `$FPATH` either defeats autoloading or plainly does not work.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

In zsh, the function search path ($fpath) defines a set of directories, which contain files that can be marked to be loaded automatically when the function they contain is needed for the first time.

Zsh has two modes of autoloading files: Zsh's native way and another mode that resembles ksh's autoloading. The latter is active if the KSH_AUTOLOAD option is set. Zsh's native mode is the default and I will not discuss the other way here (see "man zshmisc" and "man zshoptions" for details about ksh-style autoloading).

Okay. Say you got a directory `~/.zfunc' and you want it to be part of the function search path, you do this:

```
fpath=( ~/.zfunc "${fpath[@]}" )
```

That adds your private directory to the **front** of the search path. That is important if you want to override functions from zsh's installation with your own (like, when you want to use an updated completion function such as `_git' from zsh's CVS repository with an older installed version of the shell).

It is also worth noting, that the directories from `$fpath' are not searched recursively. If you want your private directory to be searched recursively, you will have to take care of that yourself, like this (the following snippet requires the `EXTENDED_GLOB' option to be set):

```
fpath=(
    ~/.zfuncs
    ~/.zfuncs/**/*~*/(CVS)#(/N)
    "${fpath[@]}"
)
```

It may look cryptic to the untrained eye, but it really just adds all directories below `~/.zfunc' to `$fpath', while ignoring directories called "CVS" (which is useful, if you're planning to checkout a whole function tree from zsh's CVS into your private search path).

Let's assume you got a file `~/.zfunc/hello' that contains the following line:

```
printf 'Hello world.\n'
```

All you need to do now is **mark** the function to be automatically loaded upon its first reference:

```
autoload -Uz hello
```

"What is the -Uz about?", you ask? Well, that's just a set of options that will cause `autoload' to do the right thing, no matter what options are being set otherwise. The `U' disables alias expansion while the function is being loaded and the `z' forces zsh-style autoloading even if `KSH_AUTOLOAD' is set for whatever reason.

After that has been taken care of, you can use your new `hello' function:

```
zsh% hello
Hello world.
```

A word about sourcing these files: That's just **wrong**. If you'd source that `~/.zfunc/hello' file, it would just print "Hello world." once. Nothing more. No function will be defined. And besides, the idea is to only load the function's code when it is **required**. After the `autoload' call the function's definition is **not** read. The function is just marked to be autoloaded later as needed.

And finally, a note about $FPATH and $fpath: Zsh maintains those as linked parameters. The lower case parameter is an array. The upper case version is a string scalar, that contains the entries from the linked array joined by colons in between the entries. This is done, because handling a list of scalars is way more natural using arrays, while also maintaining backwards compatibility for code that uses the scalar parameter. If you choose to use $FPATH (the scalar one), you need to be careful:

```
FPATH=~/.zfunc:$FPATH
```

will work, while the following will not:

```
FPATH="~/.zfunc:$FPATH"
```

The reason is that tilde expansion is not performed within double quotes. This is likely the source of your problems. If `echo $FPATH` prints a tilde and not an expanded path then it will not work. To be safe, I'd use $HOME instead of a tilde like this:

```
FPATH="$HOME/.zfunc:$FPATH"
```

That being said, I'd much rather use the array parameter like I did at the top of this explanation.

You also shouldn't export the $FPATH parameter. It is only needed by the current shell process and not by any of its children.

### Update

Regarding the contents of files in `$fpath':

With zsh-style autoloading, the content of a file is the body of the function it defines. Thus a file named "hello" containing a line `echo "Hello world."` completely defines a function called "hello". You're free to put
`hello () { ... }` around the code, but that would be superfluous.

The claim that one file may only contain one function is not entirely correct, though.

Especially if you look at some functions from the function based completion system (compsys) you'll quickly realise that that is a misconception. You are free to define additional functions in a function file. You are also free to do any sort of initialisation, that you may need to do the first time the function is called. However, when you do you will always define a function that is named like the file in the file and **call that function** at the end of the file, so it gets run the first time the function is referenced.

If - with sub-functions - you didn't define a function named like the file within the file, you'd end up with that function having function definitions in it (namely those of the sub-functions in the file). You would effectively be defining all your sub-functions every time you call the function that is named like the file. Normally, that is **not** what you want, so you'd re-define a function, that's named like the file within the file.

I'll include a short skeleton, that will give you an idea of how that works:

```
# Let's again assume that these are the contents of a file called "hello".

# You may run arbitrary code in here, that will run the first time the
# function is referenced. Commonly, that is initialisation code. For example
# the `_tmux' completion function does exactly that.
echo initialising...

# You may also define additional functions in here. Note, that these
# functions are visible in global scope, so it is paramount to take
# care when you're naming these so you do not shadow existing commands or
# redefine existing functions.
hello_helper_one () {
    printf 'Hello'
}

hello_helper_two () {
    printf 'world.'
}

# Now you should redefine the "hello" function (which currently contains
# all the code from the file) to something that covers its actual
# functionality. After that, the two helper functions along with the core
# function will be defined and visible in global scope.
hello () {
    printf '%s %s\n' "$(hello_helper_one)" "$(hello_helper_two)"
}

# Finally run the redefined function with the same arguments as the current
# run. If this is left out, the functionality implemented by the newly
# defined "hello" function is not executed upon its first call. So:
hello "$@"
```

If you'd run this silly example, the first run would look like this:

```
zsh% hello
initialising...
Hello world.
```

And consecutive calls will look like this:

```
zsh% hello
Hello World.
```

I hope this clears things up.

(One of the more complex real-world examples that uses all those tricks is the already mentioned `[_tmux](http://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Completion/Unix/Command/_tmux)' function from zsh's function based completion system.)

Comment: Thanks Frank! I read in the other answers that I can only define one function per file, is that right? I noticed you didn't use the syntax `my_function () { }` in your `Hello world` example. If the syntax is not needed, when would it be useful to use it?

Comment: I extended the original answer to address those questions as well.

Comment: “you will always define in function that is named like the file in the file and call that function at the end of the file”: why so?

Comment: Hibou57: (Aside: That's a typo there, should be "define a function", that's fixed now.) I thought that was clear, when you take the code snippet that follows into consideration. Anyway, I've added a paragraph that spells the reason out a bit more literally.

Comment: [Here](http://bewatermyfriend.org/p/2012/003/) is more info from your site, thanks.

Comment: regarding your helper functions, my zsh is happy without the `hello` definition and `hello` call. The helpers 1 and 2 are working though

Comment: Timo: If you remove the internal redefinition of the hello function within the file, the behaviour will differ from what I described in the rest of the text.

Comment: `**/*~*/(CVS)#` would be the same as `**/*~*/CVS`. I think you'd want `(^CVS/)#^CVS(/N)` here (do not include and do not descend into CVS directories)

Comment: What a superb answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Where is the `autoload -Uz hello` executed? Is it placed in `.zshrc` or run from the prompt?

Comment: vfclists: It's important to understand what the `autoload` *does*: It marks a function to be loaded automatically when  referenced first. So, if you just want to try things out, you can do it from the command line. If you want a function to be marked for autoloading in each interactive instance of zsh, you can put it into your `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Why using `fpath=( ~/.zfunc "${fpath[@]}" )` instead of just `fpath=( ~/.zfunc $fpath )` ?

Comment: It's a matter of practice: If you want to *precisely* expand all entries in an array in zsh, you use `"${foo[@]}"`. Take for example entries that are empty strings and you'll see the difference. For `$fpath` there won't be a difference in all cases, probably. But I'm using this so people see and learn the generally correct expression.

Comment: Is it possible to have the helper functions only be available in the function itself and not pollute the overall namespace?

Comment: JellyFilledNuts: Nope, zsh has a single namespace. That's why completion definitions usually use a prefix like `_tmux…` and `__tmux…` in `_tmux`.

Comment: "`z` forces zsh-style autoloading" What does this mean?

Comment: So `-Uz` says a specific function name within a file? Chris Johnsen's answer worked for [me](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/740498/how-to-retain-color-output-with-custom-zsh-function) but I had to rename my filename...

Answer (score 12):

The name of the file in a directory named by an `fpath` element must match the name of the autoloadable function it defines.

Your function is named `my_function` and `~/.my_zsh_functions` is the intended directory in your `fpath`, so the definition of `my_function` should be in the file `~/.my_zsh_functions/my_function`.

The plural in your proposed filename (`functions_1`) indicates that you were planning on putting multiple functions in the file. This is not how `fpath` and autoloading work. You should have one function definition per file.

Comment: Thanks Chris! Used this to do [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/740498/how-to-retain-color-output-with-custom-zsh-function) and now I can actually use it :) I had to rename my file `>.<`

Answer (score 12):

Sourcing definitely isn't the right approach, since what you seem to want is to have lazy initialized functions. That's what `autoload` is for. Here's how you accomplish what you're after.

In your `~/.my_zsh_functions`, you say you want to put a function called `my_function` that echos "hello world". But, you wrap it in a function call, which isn't how this works. Instead, you need to make a file called `~/.my_zsh_functions/my_function`. In it, just put `echo "Hello world"`, not in a function wrapper. You could also do something like this if you really do prefer to have the wrapper.

```
# ~/.my_zsh_functions/my_function
__my_function () {
    echo "Hello world";
}
# you have to call __my_function
# if this is how you choose to do it
__my_function
```

Next, in your `.zshrc` file, add the following:

```
fpath=(~/.my_zsh_functions $fpath);
autoload -U ~/.my_zsh_functions/my_function
```

When you load a new ZSH shell, type `which my_function`. You should see this:

```
my_function () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XU
}
```

ZSH just stubbed out my_function for you with `autoload -X`. Now, run `my_function` by just typing `my_function`. You should see `Hello world` print out, and now when you run `which my_function` you should see the function filled in like this:

```
my_function () {
    echo "Hello world"
}
```

Now, the real magic comes when you set up your whole `~/.my_zsh_functions` folder to work with `autoload`. If you want every file you drop in this folder to work like this, change what you put in your `.zshrc` to something this:

```
# add ~/.my_zsh_functions to fpath, and then lazy autoload
# every file in there as a function
fpath=(~/.my_zsh_functions $fpath);
autoload -U $fpath[1]/*(.:t)
```

Comment: On Mac OS 10.15.2 with zsh 5.7.1 I had to add a `$` infront of fpath like:
`autoload -U $fpath[1]/*(.:t)`

Comment: What happens if there is a a directory in the directory I am autoloading every file from?

Comment: You can dot that, but you'll want to use extended globbing and the double star syntax: `setopt extended_glob; autoload -U $fpath[1]/**/*(.:t)`

Comment: Why you didn't use `autoload -Uz` but only `autoload -U`? IIRC, these two options are better to be used together.

Comment: @Niing - If there's a chance `KSH_AUTOLOAD` was set somewhere in your config and you don't actually want that for your autoload functions, then sure - `autoload -Uz` ensures you are in Zsh mode when autoloading. But for most people's config that's probably not a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

give `source ~/.my_zsh_functions/functions1` in the terminal and the evaluate `my_function`, now you will be able to call the function

Comment: Thanks, but what is the role of `FPATH` and `autoload` then? Why do I also need to source the file? See my updated question.

Answer (score -1):

You can "load" a file with all your functions in your $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc like this:

```
source $ZDOTDIR/functions_file
```

Or can use a dot "." instead of "source".

Comment: Thanks, but what is the role of `FPATH` and `autoload` then? Why do I also need to source the file? See my updated question.