# zsh completion: do not offer directories when extracting archive with tar

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

the completion system for `tar` command is quite clever. When I have different archive types, it offers the relevant files depending on tar options used:

```
$ ls
file.tar.xz
file.tar.gz

$ tar xJf f<TAB>
file.tar.xz

$ tar xzf f<TAB>
file.tar.gz
```

It recognizes `xJf` as acting on `tar.xz` files, and `xzf` acting on `tar.gz` files.

But when directory exists in current location, it offers it for completion as well :

```
$ tar xJf f<TAB>
foo/   file.tar.xz
```

Can I tell the completion system, that I only want to complete files, when extracting archives (ie, `tar` option `x...`) ?

But it should still offer directories when creating archives (`tar` option `c...`):

```
tar cpJf foo.tar.xz
```

I assume this will need modifying the main completion file for `tar` command: `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_tar`. But how?

Comment: You mean you never extract archives that are not in the current working directory (as in `tar xf foo/file.tar.xz` or `tar xf ~/Downloads/file.tgz`)?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas - exactly. I `cd` to the location and then extract the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the completion system to present only files for *every* invocation of
`tar` is relatively straightforward.  This `zstyle` command added to `.zshrc`
will do the trick:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:tar:*' 'file-patterns' '*(.)'
```

This triggers code in the `_files` builtin function that restricts the
file pattern match to plain files only, via the `(.)` glob qualifier.

Unfortunately, it overrides the pattern-matching for all `tar` invocations, so
the extension-based matching in your example no longer works, and directories
are not part of the matching when creating an archive.  Changing `zsh` to
ignore directories more selectively involves getting a bit deeper into the
completion code.

---

We can accomplish this by modifying the `_tar_archive` function (thanks to
@Gilles for pointing out how).  That function already has separate handling
for extracting archives and creating archives, so we just need to change the
lines for extracting archives.

This is the modified code that does that, based on the code from my system
(macOS 10.15, zsh 5.7.1).  It calls `_path_files` directly in the extraction
cases, so that it only looks at files.  The original code used `_files`, which
looped through both files and directories.

```
#autoload

# This is used to generate filenames usable as a tar archive.  This may
# get one argument, a collection of tar option characters that may be
# used to find out what kind of filename is needed.  If no argument is
# given but the parameter `_tar_cmd' is set, that is used.
# If your version of `tar' supports this you may want to complete
# things like `host:file' or `user@host:file' here.

local expl

[[ $# -eq 0 && $+_tar_cmd -ne 0 ]] && set "$_tar_cmd"

_description files expl 'archive file'

if [[ "$1" = *[urtx]* ]]; then
  if [[ "$1" = *[zZ]* ]]; then
    _path_files "$expl[@]" -g '*.((tar|TAR).(gz|GZ|Z)|tgz)(-.)'
  elif [[ "$1" = *[Ijy]* ]]; then
    _path_files "$expl[@]" -g '*.(tar|TAR).bz2(-.)'
  elif [[ "$1" = *J* ]]; then
    _path_files "$expl[@]" -g '*.(tar|TAR).(lzma|xz)(-.)'
  elif [[ "$_cmd_variant[$service]" == (gnu|libarchive) ]]; then
    _path_files "$expl[@]" -g '*.((tar|TAR)(.gz|.GZ|.Z|.bz2|.lzma|.xz|)|(tbz|tgz|txz))(-.)'
  else
    _path_files "$expl[@]" -g '*.(tar|TAR)(-.)'
  fi
else
  _files "$expl[@]"
fi
```

---

Modifying the functions in the completion system can be slightly tricky.  It's
probably best to create copies rather than changing the release code in the
original directories.  For a quick reference, these are the commands that were
needed on my system; other systems may have different requirements.  There
are more details in this Stack Exchange answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33898/432774

One time changes:

```
mkdir ~/.zfunc
for d in $fpath; do
  [[ -f $d/_tar_archive ]] && cp $d/_tar_archive ~/.zfunc; break
done
# (edit file as noted above)

print 'fpath=( ~/.zfunc "${fpath[@]}" )' >> ~/.zshrc
# (restart shell)
```

These commands are needed after every code change.  Note that just restarting
the shell may not be sufficient:

```
unfunction _tar_archive
autoload -Uz _tar_archive

rm ~/.zcompdump
rm ~/.zcompcache/*
compinit
```

Comment: I have applied the changes to `_files` and `_tar_archive` (I also have zsh version `5.7.1`).  But when I do: `tar xpJf f<TAB>`, it still offers me directories as well as files.

Comment: @400theCat It took me a few tries to get the new code recognized, and I may not have transcribed every step correctly.  Try adding debug printouts, like `date >> ~/log.txt`, to the functions to make sure you're reaching the modified code.